# Mac : How to open the output of a CLI command in a text editor

Tags: mac, command-line, text-editors

I read how the output of a cli command and open it up in the default text editor. I lost the link to this article/blog. I kinda remember that it was using the open command to pipe the output of a command(say, ls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `open -tf`, eg, `ls | open -tf`.

Others you may find useful are the commands `pbcopy` & `pbpaste`.  These can be used to insert/retrieve the 'pasteboard' (clipboard) from the command line.

eg, `ls -l | pbcopy` and then ⌘V within the editor/application of your choice.

(`pbpaste` is obviously the same in reverse. eg, `pbpaste | grep foo` to search for a string in the clipboard.)

Comment: thank you. I already knew about pbcopy and pbpaste from googling. I somehow could not do the same about the open -tf option.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
ls | mate
```

The exact command depends on your editor of choice, I have TextMate installed as my main editor.

Comment: Does the above command open all the files in the current directory in "textmate" ? If yes, that is not what I was looking for. I was looking for the ouput of ls to be open in a temporary file in the default text editor.

Comment: no, it opens the output of the ls command in textmate.

Comment: The answer I was looking for is given below. However i'm surprised that mate takes the output that was given and instead of opening the files, it created a temp file(from the output) and opened the temp file.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the output of ls to a file and then edit that file:

```
ls > tempfile && vim tempfile
```

You can use any editor instead of vim.